# Web framework: N?DFA/Flowchart-->simple site?

Tags: web-development

I've been wishing I had a very particular sort of web framework: create a state-machine describing the of navigation and output a static website (in the simple case).

So I'd specify a set of nodes, representing the pages themselves, and edge transition rules, representing links/user actions.

The styles and templates and such would, I imagine, be specified in some config files. Likewise, I'd provide some mapping from node-->displayed content.

The particular use case is that I'd like to create flow-charts and instruction sets, and, IMHO, simple mobile-friendly sites would be a good way of presenting this information. But it is cumbersome to build these things as html, or as dynamic web apps--especially when it comes to changing the instruction set.

Hope I've described this in a useful way--if not, do let me know.